# JPA 2 Custom Entity Fields

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I was read this [article](http://www.infoq.com/articles/hibernate-custom-fields) and I'm looking for Spring – JPA based solution of this problem.

Is possible changing JPA mappings on the fly?

I found this [solution](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Extensible#Flex_Extensions), but not working... I'm using Spring / JPA / Hibernate...

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

There are ["dynamic models"](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/persistent-classes.html#persistent-classes-dynamicmodels) in Hibernate, which is similar to "Flex Extensions" you referenced. You can give it a try.

Some time ago I had to do something similar in plain JPA 2 for a PoC project (quick and dirty), and I choose to keep dynamic things as Map, serializing objects myself, looks a little bit ugly but it do the job:

```
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@ElementCollection
@MapKeyColumn(name="name")
@Column(name="value")
@CollectionTable(name="dynamic_data", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="entity_id"))
private Map<String, String> data_xml;

@Transient
private Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();

protected Map<String, String> getData_xml() { //serialize each value to string 
}

protected void setData_xml(Map<String, String> data_xml) { //convert each value from string
}
```

Of course it's not ready to be copy-pasted into production code, juts to show the idea.

**P.S.** I've found some dynamic models demo code in [hibernate sources](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/tree/master/hibernate-core/src/test/java/org/hibernate/test/dynamicentity)